# Variable auto assign

Tags: shell-script

By using `dspmq | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}'` I will get output in multiple lines. So I want to consider first line output as a `vairable1`, second line out as `variable2` and so on...
How could I do that?

Comment: What shell are you using? And what are you using the data for later? (I'm thinking you could possibly use it in the `awk` script _without_ setting shell variables)

Comment: Will assign variable in shell for other purpose.

Comment: would an array be acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean `awk` variables, it would make more sense to use an array. Like:

```
dspmq | awk -F '[()]' '
  {variable[NR] = $2}
  END {
    print "first line: "variable[1]", third line: "variable[3]
  }'
```

If you mean *shell* variable, you could do:

```
eval "$(dspmq | awk -F '[()]' -v q="'" '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }

  {print "variable"NR"="shquote($2)}'
)"
```

If using the `bash` shell, you could use an array which you could fill up with:

```
readarray -t variable < <(dspmq | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}')
```

Beware that array indices in `bash` (like in `ksh` whose design it copied) start at 0 instead of 1  (first line in `${variable[0]}`).

With `zsh`:

```
variable=("${(f@)$(dspmq | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}')}")
```

(first line in `$variable[1]`)